# Proof about the union of functions - From Velleman's "How to Prove It?"

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose $f:A\rightarrow C$ and $g : B \rightarrow C$.
(a) Prove that if A and B are disjoint, then $f\cup g : A \cup B \rightarrow C$.
(b) More generally, prove that $f\cup g:A\cup B \rightarrow C$ iff $f \restriction (A\cap B) = g \restriction (A\cap B).$

I understand that part of this question has been asked before, however the answers I found were not as complete as I would have liked.

My attempt:
(a) Suppose $A\cap B = \varnothing$, $f:A\rightarrow C,$ and $g : B \rightarrow C.   $ Then, there does not exist an element $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \in B.$ Also, by the definition of a function, $f \subseteq A\times C$. Similarly, $g \subseteq B \times C.$ It follows that $f \cup g \subseteq (A \cup B) \times C$. To show that $f\cup g : A \cup B \rightarrow C$, we must show that all elements $y \in C$ are the image under $f \cup g$ of a unique $x \in (A\cup B).$ If $x \in (A\cup B)$ then $x \in A$ or $x \in B.$ Combining this with our original supposition, we know that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, but not both. This ensures the uniqueness of our argument $x$. $\square$

(b) ($\rightarrow$) Suppose $f\cup g : A \cup B \rightarrow C$. We now try to prove $f \restriction (A\cap B) = g \restriction (A\cap B)$. This can be broken down as $f \cap ((A\cap B) \times C) = g \cap((A\cap B) \times C)$...

I'm thinking that because it is a biconditional, I must provide the proof for both "directions." I'm not sure how to approach (b) after what I have written. My instinct is telling me to prove that the two sets are equal by showing they are subsets of one another, but I just can't seem to put it into words. Please explain how (b) can be done and provide feedback on my proof for (a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f:A\to C$ is a subset of $A\times C$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is a unique $f(a)$ such that $(a,f(a))\in f.$

If $f$ restricted to $A\cap B$ is not equal to $g$ restricted to $A\cap B$ then there exists $d\in A\cap B$ such that $f(d)\ne g(d).$ Then the ordered pairs $(d,f(d)), (d,g(d))$ both belong to $f\cup g,$ with $f(d)\ne g(d),$ so $f\cup g$ is not a function.

That is equivalent to one half of (b).

Comment: So using your method, I'm not required to prove the biconditional in both directions?

Comment: No. You still have to do the other direction. I edited my last line, which was erroneous.